# 2009 Mini Cooper. How do I open the trunk?

Tags: key, mini-cooper

This is an odd question, I am sure, but we bought a used Mini Cooper, but it didn't come with an owner's manual. We have figured out how to open it with the key fob, obviously.

The problem comes when we want to pop the trunk and quickly pull something out when the car is running. This Mini doesn't have the keyless start option. So we actually have to turn off the engine to get the key out to pop the trunk.

This seems ridiculous to me, since all the other cars I have driven have a latch somewhere inside the car to pop the trunk.

Comment: There should be a latch of some kind -- maybe just a rubber-covered area that you press -- on the underside of the ledge above the license plate. You can easily find an owner's manual online if you search, too: http://libraryofmotoring.info/reference/manuals/, for example.

Comment: I was able to find that file before, I just haven't been successful. The rubber handle above the license plate doesn't seem to do anything. I am under the impression that there is a setting I have to change in the keyfob. I just have been unsuccessful in finding that setting.

Comment: Did u find a way? I have a 2008 & have the same problem. Only way we have found without turning off the car is to remove the key from fob while it is still in "ignition" and unlock that way. It's a pain!

Comment: Nope, never did. Even went to the dealer and they said "it should work," but never actually tried to do it. Have already sold that car, however. I'd recommend taking it to a dealer and actually getting the sales guy to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

I found 2003 and 2005 manuals online. It says that the central locking switch on the dash unlocks all three doors. Once unlocked, you should be able to push the button in the outside door handle, which is the lip above the license/number plate.

In the case of an electrical malfunction, you can lift the base of the rear seat, and there is a ring on a cable you can pull to release it as well.

Here is the google search I used: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22Congratulations+on+your+new+mini%22+2009+mini+%22owner%27s+manual%22+%2Bfiletype%3Apdf

Note that once I found the "congratulations..." phrase they put in other model years of their manuals, I added that literal expression to the google search. This narrowed the result to one page, which included versions up through 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2008. Make sure the trunk is unlocked and then just push in the rubber bit above the rear license plate. It can be hard to push...the actual button inside is closer to the right-hand side of the rubber.

Answer (score 0):

A second click on the remote key fob allows you to open the trunk. Also the lock key on the front dash panel gives the same result

Comment: The OP stated that the key fob is not an issue. It is that interior button they cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the latch to open the trunk would be either in the center consol or in the glove box. The reason I guess this because this car model can be convertible, normally in this case the latch to open the trunk is located somewhere you can lock it. The reason for this is to protect the content of the trunk. So if you center consol can be locked check in there or in the glove box.

Good luck!

Edit : from this [link](http://www.mini2.com/forum/second-generation-mini-cooper-s/141423-how-open-trunk.html) it look like you need to unlock all the door from the button to unlock the trunk at the same time.